# SASS Optimize Font Awesome for only used classes

Tags: css, sass, font-awesome

Is it possible to make SASS only add the code for the used icons? Because this will reduce the CSS file size,

I saw the http://fontello.com/ solution from a similar question, but I wanted to use to know if there is a way to do it with font awesome,

**Edit:**
as there was some misinterpretation, I want to clarify that what I want to know is:
**is it possible to tell SASS what icons he should compile?**

Comment: And you can with that website you posted.  There is a heading called, "Font Awesome" where you can click the FA icons that you use.  When you are finished just click download in the top right...it's that easy.

Comment: but i wanted to know if it is possible to do it with font awesome and SASS. Like saying on the SASS file the icons that i need and only those would be added.

Comment: How do you think Sass is supposed to know what you use?  Sass only compiles to CSS.

Comment: what i want to know is if it is possible to tell the sass file what icons i want him to add

Comment: should be: "what icons she should compile?" - SASS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to tell FA what to compile**

Using SCSS (SASS CSS Formal Syntax)

1. Download and extract `font-awesome-4.x.zip`
2. Navigate to `./scss`
3. Open `_icons.scss`
4. Remove the desired glyphs

Ex:

```
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-times:before { content: $fa-var-times; }
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-search-plus:before { content: $fa-var-search-plus; }
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-search-minus:before { content: $fa-var-search-minus; }
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-power-off:before { content: $fa-var-power-off; }
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-signal:before { content: $fa-var-signal; }
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-gear:before,
```

Each line represents a glyph.  Delete lines that you will not use.

5. Recompile `./font-awesome.scss` to `../css` in minified and or regular format.

Comment: I don't see how this question answers the question.  First of all, the OP is asking about Sass, not LESS.  Second of all, the OP wants Sass to magically know which icons they're using and only generate the minimum CSS necessary.

Comment: You have little to no judgement.  This post is about both SASS and less which is up to the OP which set he uses but the steps are the same.  Also this is an answer not a question.  And the OP never said anything about magic.  Get it right.  This is the answer.

Comment: @cimmano i don't want something magical, i want to know if there is any way to tell my SASS what to compile.

Comment: @rob180 I have updated my answer to the exact details needed to complete the task

Comment: This is minifying the CSS - which unfortunately has no impact on the compiled fonts - which are the main weight - use Fontello

Answer (score -1):

I used https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome

main file contains:

```
import "variables";
import "mixins";
import "path";
import "core";
import "larger";
import "fixed-width";
import "list";
import "bordered-pulled";
import "animated";
import "rotated-flipped";
import "stacked";
import "icons";
```

you must to change file _icons.scss , To make SASS only add the code for the used icons.
  change using icons

```
. # {$ fa-css-prefix} -glass: before {content: $ fa-var-glass; }
```

on mixins:

```
 mixin icon-glass () {
    . # {$ fa-css-prefix} -glass: before {content: $ fa-var-glass; }
}
```

And now with mixinx you can apply only using icons:

```
@include icon-glass();
```

You can also disable / include files

```
import "larger";
import "fixed-width";
import "list";
import "bordered-pulled";
import "animated";
import "rotated-flipped";
```

This is the easiest way to solve your problem

Comment: Having a space between the `$` and the variable name is invalid